# windows 10 screen resolution issue - text blurry

Tags: windows-10, resolution

Why is rendered text so messed up?

Here is image of screenshot zoomed on text:
[image]
Something is wrong with rendering here :D I was thinking my monitor is crap until i saw this in screenshot image.

Here are my display settings:
[image]

How to fix this?

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong here. This is known as [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) and is entirely normal.

It should look just fine at a normal zoom level, like so:

[image]

Comment: Side note: You can turn it off, but it's going to look like shit. https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/turn-off-or-on-clear-type-text-in-windows-10.html

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read this article on text scaling, particularly since it seems you just got yourself a new shiny 4K monitor. :) Your hunch is right, you shouldn’t be able to notice the sub-pixel rendering at that level on a 4K display.

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/windows-10-display-scaling/

Specifically:

> With your high resolution display connected to your PC, head to Settings > System > Display. Here, you’ll see a slider labeled Change the size of text, apps, and other items. With compatible hardware, Windows 10 will attempt to automatically set this value to an appropriate percentage when connected to a high resolution display. However, you can manually adjust it by clicking and dragging the slider. Moving the slider to the left reduces the display scaling percentage, which will make things appear relatively smaller, while moving it to the right increases the display scaling percentage, making things look relatively larger.

I’d start at 150%, as the article suggests and then adjust to your preference.

Windows can be pretty dumb with high pixel density (high DPI) displays, i.e. it almost never does the right thing out of the box. AFAIK only Mac OS has proper out of the box behaviour with high DPI displays.

Comment: Just another tip: After you change your scaling, log out and relogin. Things will go funny / blurry after you change scaling and did not log out. (Have seen this happens at my workplace many many times)

Answer (score 1):

It's [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType), you can disable it in the advanced display settings.

[Here](https://www.top-password.com/blog/turn-on-off-cleartype-text-in-windows-10/) you can find the step-by-step instructions with screenshots.